# How can I reorder the items in a QML GridLayout?

Tags: qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

How can I reorder the items in a GridLayout (or other QML item containers generally)?  I have one with some number of rows and columns and populated with child items.  Until a few minutes ago I was hoping I could simply operate on the `children` list member of the item to reorder them:  I have a `MouseArea` button in the UI from which I was hoping could simply invoke (from `onClicked:`) a

```
function reorder() {children.unshift(children.pop());}
```

method of the layout item (with the intention of the last item in the layout becoming the first), but when triggered that generates the error message:

```
TypeError: Property 'pop' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

and in any case I note the documentation says `children` is read only.

Is there an easy way of doing this?  (The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) on dynamic object management doesn't really cover more than creation and destruction of child objects.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [row](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#row-attached-prop) and [column](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#column-attached-prop) attached properties.

Comment: Ah, of course!  I can just iterate over the children and update those properties appropriately; the observed layout has nothing to do with the actual child order anyway... will try it out later and accept this answer if it works out.  Thanks; one of those cases where I just needed someone to point out the blindingly obvious :^)

Answer (score 2):

Following Mitch's answer, I came up with this:

```
  function reorder() {
    for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
      var index=columns*children[i].Layout.row + children[i].Layout.column;
      var newIndex=(index+1)%(rows*columns);
      children[i].Layout.row=Math.floor(newIndex/columns)%rows;
      children[i].Layout.column=newIndex%columns;
    }
  }
```

There are a few caveats:

- For this to work you have to have explicitly set a `Layout.row` and `Layout.column` on the contained items already.  If you rely on the `GridLayout`'s cell assignment, the attached properties remain zero.  This was a bit surprising as I initially read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) as implying the GridLayout actually set these itself if you didn't.
- You also need to have set `rows` and `columns` on the layout explicitly (for left to right layouts you can get away with just setting columns for layout wrapping purposes... but then the rows property remains -1 regardless of how many rows of child items are added, and the above code will fail).
- It spits out some console warnings like `QGridLayoutEngine::addItem: Cell (1, 1) already taken` as the items are shuffled along.  Seems to be harmess enough though.
- Obviously the above is only really expecting to deal with a fully populated grid of single cell items.

Answer (score 2):

You can do pop/push-like operations as initially described by changing the parent of the items in the GridLayout. Pop any item from any index in the GridLayout by un-parenting it from the GridLayout. Push to the end of the GridLayout by re-parenting it to the GridLayout again. Between these two operations, you could insert items at any location by pushing and popping all of the children in a specific order and not otherwise have to manage row/column on each item, leaving automatic layout to the GridLayout.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 600
    width: 800

    GridLayout {
        id: grid
        columns: 4
        Rectangle {
            id: rect1
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, 1)
            height: 20
            width: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect2
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, 1)
            height: 20
            width: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect3
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, 1)
            height: 20
            width: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect4
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, 1)
            height: 20
            width: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: rect5
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, Math.random()*0.5 + 0.25, 1)
            height: 20
            width: 20
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: item
        visible: false
    }

    Button {
        text: "push first item to rear of gridview"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: {
                var object = grid.children[0] 
                object.parent = item // pop from grid
                object.parent = grid // push to grid
        }
    }
}
```